# Use isShiftDown() twice

Tags: java, keypress, keylistener

I'm working on a small game where i need to use isShiftDown twice, the first time when he uses Shift+click, a box become green, when he Shift+click the second time on the same box she changes color and becomes red. This is what i've done but it doesnt work, infact the first time i shift+click on a box she becomes green ((byte)6), but i don't know how to shift+click a second time.

```
boolean count = false;
public synchronized void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    synchronized (gameModel) {
        int width = getGameX(e) ;
        int height = getGameY(e) ;
        if (e.isShiftDown() && count == false){
            gameModel.set(width, height, (byte)6);
            count = true;
        }
        if (e.isShiftDown() && count == true){}
        else {
            byte c = (byte)1 ;
            gameModel.set(width,height,c);
        }
        notify(gameModel) ;
    }
```

Comment: Your first `if` block sets `count` to true. Your second if block checks if `count` is true (which it definitely is, because you just set it true), so the `else` block cannot ever fire.

Comment: @khelwood please post as answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `if` block sets `count` to true. Your second `if` block checks if `count` is true (which it definitely is, because you just set it true), so the else block cannot ever fire.

Perhaps you meant something more like this:

```
if (e.isShiftDown() && !count){
    gameModel.set(width, height, (byte) 6);
    count = true;
} else if (e.isShiftDown()) {
    byte c = (byte) 1;
    gameModel.set(width,height,c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but i think this should work (delete the second if-statement like in the following code):

```
boolean count = false;
public synchronized void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    synchronized (gameModel) {
        int width = getGameX(e) ;
        int height = getGameY(e) ;
        if (e.isShiftDown() && count == false){
            gameModel.set(width, height, (byte)6);
            count = true;
        }else if (e.isShiftDown() && count == true){
            byte c = (byte)1 ;
            gameModel.set(width,height,c);
        }
        notify(gameModel) ;
    }
```